# Using Let's encript SSL certificates on OpenShift for node app

Tags: node.js, ssl, openshift, lets-encrypt

I have a node/socket.io chat app on OpenShift. The directory layout is the following:

[image: FTP view]

I would like to start using SSL on the site, specifically with Let's Encrypt, which is free. However, no matter how many tutorials I Google and try out (on a separate hosting for testing, of course), I simply can't make it work properly.

I'm sure to some this is a silly question, but I'd appreciate if someone could tell me how to do this with OpenShift.

If anyone knows of an easy to understand, step by step tutorial, I would appreciate a link.

Comment: SO isn't the place to look for tutorials, so I removed it out of the actual problem statement. Just for future reference.

Comment: Thank you, i'll take it into account in the future :)

Comment: I'm having same problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453203/how-to-get-letsencrypt-to-work-on-openshift-site     Find the answer?

Comment: Never found an answer. For something so "simple". no one has a laymans explanation. I used clouflare in the end, it simplifies a lot. Good luck