# How to get letsencrypt to work on Openshift site

Tags: https, openshift, lets-encrypt

I hope someone can help me get my site set up with HTTPS correctly on Openshift.  Here's the steps I took:

1. I have an Openshift site let's call it - myOSsite-myname.rhcloud.com
2. I have a domain name through GoDaddy -- mydomain.com.
3. I've set my domain on GoDaddy to forward to Openshift so now:
   www.mydomain.com --> myOSsite-myname.rhcloud.com
4. I set up two aliases on Openshift -- mydomain.com & www.mydomain.com
5. I went through some letsencrypt tutorials to manually generate a
   certificate.  So now the call 
   www.mydomain.com/well-known/acme-challenge/m2u0rNcFd4YnVHXqOWSFfh0G8kD2jtjAp8D8fC8Lwzg
   returns the required  hash.
6. I uploaded the generated key files to Openshift on the alias www.mydomain.com

But now when I call www.mydomain.com all I get is the hash.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: https://servicesblog.redhat.com/2019/03/15/dynamic-ssl-certificates-using-letsencrypt-on-openshift/
Read this blog, it might help.